# Find $\text{int,cl},\partial A$ for $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\ell}$ (sorgenfrey line)

Tags: general-topology

> a. Find $\text{int A,cl A and}\partial A$ for $A=[2,5]\cup\{-\frac 3 n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (Assuming $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\ell}$).
>
> b. Find the connectedness component of the singleton ${5}$ in $\mathbb{R}_{\ell}$.

About A: since $cl(A\cup B)=cl(A)\cup cl(B)$ (and similarly for the interior) so denoting $A\prime=\{-\frac 3 n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$: $$cl(A)=cl([2,5])\cup cl(A^\prime) \\ int(A)=int([2,5])\cup int(A^\prime)$$since $[2,5]$ is closed $cl[2,5]=[2,5]$ and the maximal open subset which is contained in it is $[2,5)$ so as far as I see$$cl[2,5]=[2,5]\wedge int([2,5])=[2,5)$$ but as for $A^\prime$ I don't know from where to start.In fact $A^\prime\subset[-3,0)$ but I don't know how to continue from here.

About B: What's the meaning of "connectedness component" for a singleton ? Does it mean the component it lies within?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}_l$?

Comment: sorgenfrey line defined by $\tau=\{ \underset { i\in I }{ \cup  } [{ a }_{ i },{ b }_{ i })|{ a }_{ i },{ b }_{ i }\in \mathbb{R},i\in I\}$

Answer (score 0):

The Sorgenfrey line is a topological space which is totally discontinuous: every 2 different points are contained in clopen disjoints sets. We show that every bounded interval is clopen:
$$[a,b)^c=(-\infty,a)\cup[b,+\infty)=\bigcup_{n<a}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}[n,a)\cup\bigcup_{m>b}_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}[b,m)$$
which shows that the complement of an open bounded interval [a,b) is the union of open sets and thus open. With this we see that the line is totally disconnected and as such the singletons are the biggest connected components in it.

For the first question on the other side $A$ is closed. The topology of the Sorgenfrey line is called the lower limit topology because the sequences converge only from the right, thus $A'$ is closed. On the other hand the line is a Hausdorff space thus implying that the singletons are closed and as such $[2,5]$ is closed. So we get that $cl(A)=A$.

For the interior you get what you expect because no interval is contained in $A'$ and as such $int(A')=\emptyset$ and as you already said $int([2,5])=[2,5)$. From this we have finished because:
$$int(A)=[2,5)$$
$$\partial A=cl(A)\setminus int(A)=A\setminus[2,5)=A'\cup\{5\}$$

Comment: Note that $( 0, +\infty )$ is open in the Sorgenfrey line, but its complement $( -\infty , 0]$ is not (no open set in the Sorgenfrey line has a maximum element), and so $(0,+\infty)$ is not closed in the space.

Comment: @kingofcarrotflowers Are you referring to the fact that I said open interval instead of bounded open interval? I implicitly intended it, but i corrected it.

Comment: I'm referring to your first sentence which states "_... every open set is closed and vice versa."_

Comment: It isn’t true that every bounded interval is clopen: $(0,1]$ is a bounded interval that is neither open nor closed. What you mean (and have proved) is that every interval of the form $[a,b)$ is clopen. (Indeed, a bounded interval is clopen iff it is of this form.)

Comment: I implied that in this setting interval would mean the left-closed right-open interval.